# 32bit displacement, near call, real mode

Tags: x86, call, real-mode

Suppose we have near relative call x86 instruction.

```
E8 offset      // offset from the next instruction
```

Size of offset is determined by current operand size.

In 32bit protected mode:

```
E8 rel32      // target 32bit address = add_32bit(eip, rel32)
66 E8 rel16   // target 32bit address = zero_extend_32bit(add_16bit(ip, rel16))
```

In 64bit mode:

```
E8 rel32     // target 64bit address = add_64bit(rip, sign_extend_64bit(rel32))
66 E8 rel16     // target 64bit address = zero_extend_64bit(add_16bit(ip, rel16))
```

In real mode:

```
E8 rel16     // target 16bit address = add_16bit(ip, rel16)
```

What I don't understand is what happens if we have 32bit displacement in real mode? One possible way:

```
66 E8 rel32  // target 16bit address = truncate_16bit(add_32bit(eip, rel32))
```

So in this case ip will be loaded with target 16bit address. But another possible scenario is that eip will be loaded with target 32bit address and if it is > 0xFFFF protection fault will be generated.

So what happens with `66 E8 rel32` in real mode? Thanks.

Comment: I'd guess that IP is truncated to 16-bit after the operation.  It won't modify CS, so I'm pretty sure it's not actually useful, but interesting question about what does happen.  It's obscure enough that it would be worth checking real hardware, not just an emulated CPU in BOCHS, unless someone's sure about the right answer without checking.

Comment: So this implies we can assume that rel32 is truncated to rel16 and added to ip.

Comment: Yeah, if my guess is correct, then the `66` operand-size prefix has no effect on relative (direct) near jumps / calls in 16-bit mode, other than padding the instruction length by 3 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helps me.

Comment: A relative 32 bit jump exceeding the limit of the _CS_ segment is suppose to throw a GP fault. In real mode the _CS_ segment has a limit of 0xffff so if your target is outside that it will raise a GP fault per the [instruction set reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) . With that being said, it is possible to change the limit of the _CS_ register so that it is 0xffffffff. This is called [big unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode). If in this mode a relative 32bit call will not throw a GP since the entire range 0x0 to 0xffffffff is within the CS segment limit.

Comment: Can we assume that all real mode 32 bit references to either code segment or data segment that exceed the limit will throw a GP fault? For example lets take 32 bit moffset or far call with 32 bit offset. In first case it is the limit of segment containing memory operand. In second case it is the limit of target segment.